# How to uninstall add-in from the "Excel Online"

Tags: office-js

Once I side-loaded the Excel addin on Excel Online, how do we uninstall it? I don't see any option for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you clear your browser cache, I think a sideloaded Add-in on Office Online should become "uninstalled".  Let me know if that doesn't seem to be the case for you.

Comment: "To remove an add-in sideloaded to Office on the web, simply clear your browser's cache. If you make changes to your add-in's manifest (for example, update file names of icons or text of add-in commands), you may need to clear your browser's cache and then re-sideload the add-in using the updated manifest. Doing so allows Office on the web to render the add-in as it's described by the updated manifest." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing#remove-a-sideloaded-add-in
Or you can side-load your add-ins in browser private mode to avoid

Answer (score 2):

@Michael Zlatkovsky - Clearing the browser cache worked for me but only once I closed and restarted my browser.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant add-in information seems to be stored in local storage and clearing local storage for `https://euc-excel.officeapps.live.com` gets rid of side-loaded add-ins. The hostname may be slightly different depending on region.

In chrome the steps are:

1. Open Developer Tools (Shift+CTRL+J (on Linux/Windows) or Option+⌘+J (on macOS)).
2. Application tab -> Storage -> Local Storage.
3. Right-click `https://euc-excel.officeapps.live.com` and select 'Clear'.
4. Reload the page.

Comment: The exact same steps works for Edge too.

Comment: One more step is missing, that is you need to open the appropriate office application in the browser for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate is to open the workbook in Excel desktop, and use Document Inspector to remove any Task Pane apps. Select **File > Info** menu in Excel desktop, and click **Check for Issues**, and choose **Inspect Document** to scan and remove any Task pane apps.

Ref: [Remove hidden data and personal information by inspecting workbooks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-workbooks-fdcb68f4-b6e1-4e92-9872-686cc64b6949?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)